# Ghostscript /stackunderflow in CMap definition

Tags: ghostscript

I'm trying to create a simple CMap with mapping for two CIDs. Any idea what's wrong with following CMap?

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
13 dict begin
begincmap /CIDSystemInfo <<
/Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (Identity) /Supplement 0 >> def
/CMapName /CM def
/CMapType 1 def
1 begincodespacerange
<00> <02>
endcodespacerange

2 begincidchar
<01> 6691
<02> 6692
endcidchar
endcmap CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource
pop end end
```

gs interpreter throws following error:

```
Error: /stackunderflow in --index--
Operand stack:
   1   --nostringval--   (\002)   6691   (\001)   (\000\000\000\002)   ()   (\032#)   0   (\001)   10
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1992   1   3   %oparray_pop   1991   1   3   %oparray_pop   1979   1   3   %oparray_pop   1833   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1   --nostringval--   %repeat_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:730/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:38/38(ro)(G)--   --dict:8/13(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 270
GPL Ghostscript 9.27: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Comment: I think you may have found a bug in the Ghostscript cmap parsing, it would be good if you could open a bug at https://bugs.ghostscript.com/.

Comment: In the meantime, as a workaround, I think the following will work:

/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
13 dict begin
begincmap /CIDSystemInfo <<
/Registry (Adobe) /Ordering (Identity) /Supplement 0 >> def
/CMapName /CM def
/CMapType 1 def
2 begincodespacerange
<01> <01>
<02> <02>
endcodespacerange

1 begincidchar
<01> 6691
endcidchar

1 begincidchar
<02> 6692
endcidchar

endcmap CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource
pop end end

Comment: With "formatting": https://pastebin.com/iQjAgQ6b

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've raised bug https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=704089

Comment: Thanks for opening the bug - I'll look at it as soon as I can, unless someone else gets to it before me.

Comment: Turned out to be easier to resolve than I feared: https://git.ghostscript.com/?p=ghostpdl.git;a=commitdiff;h=9d26a86aa2e

Answer (score 0):

This was a [bug](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=704089) which is fixed now.

> For individual code mappings (endnotdefchar/endcidchar) we check if the
> previous mapping values are adjacent to the current one, so we can optimize by
> merging them into a range. Each map involves 5 entries on the stack, and the
> check to trigger the attempt to merge checked for >5 entries on the stack. That
> works as long as the number of mappings is large enough that we always have at
> least 10 entries (the merging code will cope with unprocessed entries).
> In this case, we only have two mappings, when we reach the check for a marge
> condidate, there are seven entries on the stack (5 for the current, 2 for the
> remaining mapping), and we end up with a stackunderflow error, because code
> expects at least 10 objects on the stack.

Thanks @chrisl